# Facebook iOS SDK, Logout (CloseAndClearTokenInformation) not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios7

I've set up the Facebook iOS SDK with my app, and everything works fine. I can login using Facebook, but for some reason when I try and click my "Logout" button (top right, see image below), it doesn't do anything. I'm using a Storyboard to create my app (the login xib opens on top of my existing storyboard), and everything in my AppDelegate seems correct. What am I missing? See snippets of code below.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 self.mainViewController = [[SSViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"SSViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                      initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // Yes, so just open the session (this won't display any UX).
        [self openSession];
    } else {
        // No, display the login page.
        [self showLoginView];

    }
        return YES;

}

    - (void)showLoginView
    {
        UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];
        UIViewController *modalViewController = [topViewController modalViewController];

        // If the login screen is not already displayed, display it. If the login screen is
        // displayed, then getting back here means the login in progress did not successfully
        // complete. In that case, notify the login view so it can update its UI appropriately.
        if (![modalViewController isKindOfClass:[SSLoginViewController class]]) {
            SSLoginViewController* loginViewController = [[SSLoginViewController alloc]
                                                          initWithNibName:@"SSLoginViewController"
                                                          bundle:nil];
            [topViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        } else {
             SSLoginViewController* loginViewController =
            (SSLoginViewController*)modalViewController;
            [loginViewController loginFailed];
        }
    }
```

**SSViewController.m**

```
-(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
   [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(logoutButtonWasPressed:)];
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be more specific about it "not doing anything"? Are you breaking execution to check for the activeSession state and it's still open?

Comment: @ChrisLavender I assume that the session is active, as whenever I run the app, it brings me to that screen (which means I'm already logged in). If the session wasn't active, the app would open to my login screen.

Comment: Right. Then call [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; then break and check the activeSession state. Is it then closed? If not then the call isn't working. If so and you are logged back in when returning, then maybe a cache needs clearing?

Comment: @ChrisLavender Hey Chris, I got the logout working by adding that small bit to the AppDelegate.m (see edits). But when users successfully login, they get "SSViewcontroller" the xib file. How can I send them to a view controller on my storyboard?